# How to handle Task preemption corner cases in RTOS

Tags: embedded, rtos, autosar

Suppose there are two tasks in a RTOS : TASKL (low priority) and TASKH (high priority). RTOS follows priority based preemption scheduling. TASKL performs three opertions : a) Read a sensor value using a volatile variable. b) manipulate value read (say multiply by 10). c) send value to another component.
Now assume a scenario in which TASKL has executed statement a and then got interrupted by TASKH. In the meantime, sensor value also got updated by an interrupt. When TASKL resumes, will it resume from statement b ? If yes, then will it have updated sensor value or the old sensor value ? Also please let me know how can we avoid this ?

Comment: Not sure what you really trying to achieve or what the problem is. Do not use the the volatile (shared) variable itself for calculation and use a local variable to fetch the value from the volatile variable. .However, it’s better to signal the changed value from the ISR to the task e.g. using a queue.

Comment: This would be a design flaw in your scheduling and priority allocation.  Ask a about a real problem rather than an unlikely hypothetical one.  The design should be such that a) TASKL can complete its processing before a new value becomes available, b the execution time of TAKSH should not be so long as to cause TASKL to mis its deadline.  Also post real code to illustrate the problem - it is not clear what the relevance of the volatile is in this scenario.  The quick-and-dirty solution is to wrap the sensor processing in a mutex or critical section.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the actual code. What you write, gives the following:

```
//a
int val = sensor_volatile_val;

//b
val *= 10;

//c
put_into_queue(val);
```

The code above will not suffer from scheduling errors, (on most platforms) as the volatile read is most likely atomic. This can be improved (on most platforms), by an explicit atomic read:

```
int val = atomic_read32(sensor_volatile_val);
```

However, it *is* important that the sensor_volatile_val *is* actually defined as volatile. (Seeing that it's updated by an interrupt.) The interrupt gives the potiential race condition. Not the scheduling.
The scheduling issues, can happen in statement "c". "send value to another component" is rather ambigious.

My "put_into_queue" is ofc, a proper mutex protected RTOS feature ^^
I don't know about yours though.

Btw, to answer some of your question: No, even though the sensor interrupt has triggered and updated the sensor_volatile_val, statement "b" will still use the "old" value that it read previously.

If you, for some reason, don't want to use an "old" sensor value. You can verify the value, before putting it into the queue:

```
if( old_sensor_val != sensor_volatile_val) goto start;
```

But that'll rarely make sense, when dealing with normal "sensors".

Answer (score 0):

As a fun little wrinkle, gcc can sometimes behave very oddly if an object which isn't qualified as `volatile` is modified in ways the compiler isn't expecting.  The code ARM gcc 10.2.1 generates when using options `-mcpu=cortex-m0 -O2` for

```
unsigned short test(unsigned short *p)
{
  unsigned short temp = *p;
  return temp - (temp >> 15);
}
```

will return 0xFFFF if the value of `*p` changes between 0xFFFF and 0 during execution of that function, or vice versa, even though the function only reads `*p` once, and would return 0xFFFE if `*p` was read as 0xFFFF and zero if it`*p` was read as zero.